# Perform action and redirect in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, redirect, get

I have a method in my model in which i have my logic. I want a view which calls this method and redirects.

I guess it's something like:

```
class EmailMakePrimary(RedirectView):
    url = reverse('settings')

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.make_primary()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.url)
```

I've tried

```
class ArticleCounterRedirectView(RedirectView): 
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk): 
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk) 
        article.update_counter() 
        return reverse('product_detail', args=(pk,))
```

and it works a few times but suddenly just stops working.

Comment: Have you browsed through the tutorial for Django? It will help you do just this.

Comment: I've tried

class ArticleCounterRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
        article.update_counter()
        return reverse('product_detail', args=(pk,))

and it Works a few times, but suddently stops working. The method simply doesn't get called, so I was wondering if there was a more correct way doing it.

Comment: Could you update your question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to use POST http requests to the server if you are about to change something on it.  For example, POST requests never get cached.

For example:

```
class EmailMakePrimary(View):
    url = reverse('settings')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.make_primary()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.url)
```

Comment: I prefer POST too, but I don't know how to make the HTML. I need several buttons to do different things for each record, so I can't use a simple submit.

Comment: You can either use multiple `<form>`s and view functions or multiple `<submit name="foo">` and use `if 'foo' in request.POST`.